# Hovering a div but not its a links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple function that shows a hidden div `.dida` when hovering another div `.contacts`

```js
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".contacts", function() {
      $(".dida").addClass("block")
    })
    
    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".contacts", function() {
      $(".dida").removeClass("block")
    })
```

```css
.dida{opacity:0}
.block{opacity:1}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts">A B C D E F G H I J K <a href="#">LINK</a> M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</div>
<div class="dida">VOILA</div>
```

How can I avoid to show that hidden div if I'm hovering an `a` inside the `.contacts` div?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. Include the relevant HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event handler on the link and use mouseover for both the link and the div.

```js
$(document).on("mouseover", ".contacts", function() {
  $(".dida").addClass("block")
})
$(document).on("mouseleave", ".contacts", function() {
  $(".dida").removeClass("block")
})
$('div.contacts > a').mouseover(function(e) {
  $(".dida").removeClass("block")
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.dida {
  opacity: 0
}
.block {
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contacts">A B C D E F G H I J K <a href="#">LINK</a> M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z</div>
<div class="dida">VOILA</div>
```

Comment: much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well in native JavaScript you can use event propagation like.

```
addEventListener("event",  function(),  true/false);
```

Where hover is an event, function is an action and false tells the DOM to perform a bubbling event.
It has to go like this:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener("hover", function(), false);

document.getElementById('p').addEventListener("hover", function(), false);
```

Where 'p' is inside the 'div'. You can check for similar codes in Jquery i guess.
[Check this out](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)